# How long is a festival?

Tags: kittens-game

I just bought `Drama and Poetry` so now I can `start a Festival`

When I hover over the festival button is says

> Hold a culture festival to make your kittens happy.(30% to the
>   happines for a year).

I don't really understand it. Does this mean a festival is a full year, or is a festival until the end of a year?

Comment: I'm not that far in the game sadly, so can try and see if it ends at the end of the year. Best way to know, wait till the year is near its end and start one. Hopefully it will last a year.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you click on the button `hold festival` a timer will start and will count down from 400 to 0.

When te timer hits 0 the bonus effect of 30% happiness will end and you have to spend another 
`1500 Manpower`, `5000 culture` and `2500 Parchment` to get the 30% happines bonus.

So **a festival will take for 400 days and not until the end of a year.**

Festival don't stack so if you have enough resources to start another festival before the first 
festival is over you won't have a festival that is longer than 400 days

**the code:**

```
holdFestival: function(){
        this.game.calendar.festivalDays = 400;  //nope, they don't stack
        this.game.msg("The cultural festival has started");
        //TODO: some fun message like Molly Chalk is making a play 'blah blah'
    },
```

and

```
onNewDay: function(){

        if (this.festivalDays){
            this.festivalDays--;
        }
```

Comment: I really wish it added 400 days rather than setting it to 400 days.  This game really needs to be more hands-off friendly!

Answer (score 11):

**It is a whole year**:

Below is the code that executes when you actually hold a festival (so press on the button). You see that there are 400 festival days. That is exactly the amount of days in a kitten-year. (from [village.js](http://bloodrizer.ru/games/kittens/village.js?v=0.9.9.5))

```
holdFestival: function(){
    this.game.calendar.festivalDays = 400;  //nope, they don't stack
    this.game.msg("The cultural festival has started");
    //TODO: some fun message like Molly Chalk is making a play 'blah blah'
},
```

and each day such a festival day is subtracted, shown in the following code: (from [calendar.js](http://bloodrizer.ru/games/kittens/calendar.js?v=0.9.9.5))

```
onNewDay: function(){

    if (this.festivalDays){
        this.festivalDays--;
    }
```